# Installed TeXMaker with an error

Tags: texmaker

As the below figure when I run my TeX file I am getting this error[image]

Comment: you should probably start by explaining which OS you are on. I can see that I are using MikTeX and it is not Windows. Exactly where do you get this error? What did you do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That error message tells you what to do: look at that .log file. Did you? If you did and still don't know what to do, post the log file somewhere (e.g., a pastebin site) so we can look at it. (And yes, do tell us what OS you're using.)